# Problem updating record in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, readonly

This is my code:

```
try {

     myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH+"DatabaseName", MODE_APPEND, null);

     ContentValues updateRating = new ContentValues();
     updateRating.put("rating", 5);
     myDB.update(TableName1, updateRating, "id=?", new String[] {Long.toString(1)});

     ContentValues novotes = new ContentValues();
     novotes.put("no_of_votes", 1);
     myDB.update(TableName1, novotes, "id=?", new String[] {Long.toString(1)});
     }
    catch(Exception e) {
     Log.e("Error", "Error", e);
    } finally {
     if (myDB != null)
      myDB.close();
    }
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560): Error
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error code 8: **attempt to write a readonly database**
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1692)
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1622)
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560):     at com.db.mak.DataBaseWork.onCreate(DataBaseWork.java:30)
04-27 14:31:34.026: ERROR/Error(1560):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

Would really appreciate some quick help...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `myDB.open()` after `myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase`